# Threading with progress bar

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, .net-4.5

Ok, I am having an issue with how to create and manage threads. Below is some sample code, with the method call that is slowing everything down commented (`sendMail`).

Part of the problem is, I need to keep the user alerted to the progress of the send mail.  Running this on the UI thread has been making it where the form doesn't repaint after each message is sent. Not to mention I believe threading will actually speed up this program by a large amount.

```
private void btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Stop user from clicking send multiple times
    btn_send.Enabled = false;

    // Reset Progress Bar
    progressBar1.Value = 0;

    // Get User List
    List<string[]> mycsv = csvRead();

    //Get info for progress bar
    int total = mycsv.Count;

    // Send Message to each user
    for (int x = 0; x < total; x++)
    {
        // Visual Diplay, but not updating
        txt_percent.Text = "Sending Message " + 
            x.ToString() + " of " + total.ToString();

        //Actual send message
        //This can take up to 10 seconds PER user
        sendMail(mycsv[x][0], mycsv[x][1]); 

        // Update Progress Bar
        progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Round(((float)x / (float)total) * 100);
    }

    // Alert user to completion
    txt_percent.Text = "Finished";

    //Allow them to send again (hopefully with new message ;)
    btn_send.Enabled = true;            
}
```

How can I convert this to use threading, and keep using a progress bar?

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: How can I convert this to use threading, and keep using a progress bar

Comment: What version of .NET?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012, Windows Form Application, .NET Framework is 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a rough implementation with a background worker.  Feel free to tweak as needed:

```
BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bg.IsBusy) return;
    progressBar1.Value = 0;

    bg.DoWork += bg_DoWork;
    bg.ProgressChanged += bg_ProgressChanged;
    bg.RunWorkerCompleted += bg_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bg.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Alert user to completion
    txt_percent.Text = "Finished";
}

void bg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Visual Diplay, but not updating
    txt_percent.Text = e.UserState.ToString();

    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Get info for progress bar
    int total = 25;

    // Send Message to each user
    for (int x = 0; x < total; x++)
    {
        //Actual send message
        sendMail();
        bg.ReportProgress((int)Math.Round(((float)x / (float)total) * 100), "Sending Message " + x.ToString() + " of " + total.ToString());
    }

}

private void sendMail()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```